# How to open files in eshell with wildcards

Tags: eshell

I am very used to typing in a shell something like:

```
emacsclient **/Threshold.java
```

Where `Threshold.java` is a file deeply nested in a directory and I just want to
open it by name.

When I try the same thing in eshell, I get (ec is an alias for `find-file`):

```
ec **/Threshold.java
Wrong type argument: stringp, ("src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/shield/admin/Threshold.java")
```

How can I get this working in eshell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(defun eshell/my-find-file (pattern)
  (mapc #'find-file (mapcar #'expand-file-name pattern)))
```

then use `my-find-file **/Threshold.java` from Eshell, if you also want `my-find-file` to support non-glob pattern (for example, `my-find-file Threshold.java`), try following:

```
(defun eshell/my-find-file (pattern)
  (if (stringp pattern)
      (find-file pattern)
    (mapc #'find-file (mapcar #'expand-file-name pattern))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
mapcar #'find-file **/Threshold.java
```

This only works if `**/Threshold.java` expands to exactly one file. Otherwise, the second file will be opened through a relative path, but based on the directory of the first file instead of the directory where the command was executed.

Comment: The key is that for eshell the wildcard becomes double *

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this handy function:

```
(defun eshell/for-each (cmd &rest args)
    (let ((fn (intern cmd))
          (dir default-directory))
      (dolist (arg (eshell-flatten-list args))
        (let ((default-directory dir))
          (funcall fn arg)))))
```

Notice the directory handling. You can then call, for example, `for-each find-file **/Threshold.java OtherFileToo.java`.

To open files from eshell I use this: `alias ff for-each find-file $*`.